# Demodulation with a phase difference

Tags: rf, demodulation

This is an RF-based question. My professor told me that demodulating a TX signal that is 90 degrees out of phase with the receiver oscillator is impossible; there will be no baseband signal. He said that the TX and RX signal need to be in-phase in order for demodulation to work correctly. He also said that the way around this is quadrature demodulation. However, I have seen many RX circuits that use a single oscillator and a single mixer. How do they solve the problem of TX/RX phase synchronization?

Comment: Do you mean to say, "I have seen many ***RX*** circuits that use a single oscillator and single mixer"? Frankly, the TX circuit doesn't care what the phase is; the responsibility of phase locking falls on the RX circuit.

Comment: True. Also, "the TX and RX signal need to be in-phase" implies that the TX (transmitter) and RX (receiver) must be exactly a whole number of wavelengths apart. The question needs rewording so it addresses the subject of quadrature demodulating a received signal using a phase-locked local oscillator.

Comment: Yes I meant RX. Do active mixers implement a phase-lock circuit? The simple rx circuits I have seen have no PLL.

Comment: Can you provide an example RX circuit that you're thinking of? We can make speculations, but it would be best to see what you're seeing.

Comment: Look again. If you are going to encode information in phase or frequency, you're going to have to sense both. PLLs and local oscillators are integrated in all kinds of neat little packages these days. Receiving without one means you might've been looking at AM.

Comment: It's probably important to mention that these are all AM receivers. But my professor said that there would be no baseband if the RX was mixed out of phase, so it seems the modulation doesn't matter.

Comment: ...yeah, I'd say that's pretty important. /chuckle>

Comment: Can you elaborate when you're done chuckling?

Comment: Again, can you provide example circuits? What your professor said is true: a mixer whose reference is in quadrature to the signal will output nothing. We can offer speculations about how the RX circuits you're referring to avoid this, but it's best if we see some examples.

Comment: Here is a schematic: http://mightydevices.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/receiver.png

Comment: Shucks, I was hoping for a PLL or an oscillator that was particularly sensitive to injection locking. Either that, or mixing to an IF followed by asynchronous demodulation. With this receiver, when tuned near the carrier, you should experience a sort of beating and fading as the LO and carrier walk past each other. I think you can get around it with single sideband (SSB) AM modulation.

Comment: To understand crocboy's receiver schematic you need the data sheet of the SA612 double-balanced mixer and oscillator. http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/philips/SA612.pdf
Crocboy's schematic shows a VTUNE input that could be used to lock the oscillator to complete a PLL. This is not a complete receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to transmit the message signal \$m(t)\$ and you upconvert it by multiplying it by a cosine, so that the actual signal transmitted is \$s(t)=m(t)\cos(2\pi f_ct)\$ . This is called AM DSB-SC (double side-band suppressed carrier). If you multiply \$s(t)\$ with \$\cos(2\pi f_ct)\$ and low-pass filter the result, you get \$m(t)\$.

However, if you multiply \$s(t)\$ with \$\cos(2\pi f_ct+\phi)\$, then the result after the low-pass filter is \$m(t)\cos(\phi)\$. If \$\phi\$ is close to \$\pi/2\$ or \$3\pi/2\$, the received signal is close to zero. There are several solutions, along these two lines:

- Use a phase-recovery circuit in the receiver, such as a PLL. This adds a bit to the system's complexity and cost. This is the most common solution these days for all but the simplest receivers.
- For a very cheap system, let the user adjust the antenna positions to improve the reception.

A third solution is to transmit \$s(t)=(A+m(t))\cos(2\pi f_ct)\$, where \$A\$ is large enough to make \$A+m(t)\$ be always positive. This is called AM DSB-LC (double side-band large carrier). Essentially, you're transmitting the carrier along with your signal, so the receiver can figure out exactly what phase you used. An envelope detector is a circuit that recovers \$m(t)\$ in this case. The downside is that a lot of power goes to transmit the carrier instead of the message.

Quadrature transmission is a way to profit from this fact by transmitting two messages with the same carrier frequency; one message is transmitted with a carrier that is \$\pi/2\$ radians out of phase with the other. Using similar carriers in the receiver, both messages can be recovered. Of course, in this case a very good phase estimation is essential.